# How can I share XAML UserControls between VS projects?

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, nuget

I have a Portable Class Library project targeting Windows 8.1. The project has some normal C# files (template controls), and some XAML Page files (user controls).

When I build the project, I get the following in the bin/Release folder.

- *user_controls*

  - *example*.xbf
- Themes

  - Generic.xbf
- *project*.dll
- *project*.pdb
- *project*.pri
- *project*.xr.xml

These files are enough to deploy and run a test harness for the library in the same solution. I'd like to know how to package these files so that I can use them in other projects/solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I found how to do this by trial and error. The package manager of choice for VS projects seems to be Nuget, for which the package file structure is as follows.

- *project*

  - *user_controls*

    - *example*.xbf
  - Themes

    - Generic.xbf
  - *project*.xr.xml
- *project*.dll
- *project*.pdb
- *project*.pri

The above goes in the **lib** folder. I'd be happy to here about a better (or less haphazard) way of doing this. But at least it works!

Comment: Note: I did find that I get a XAML parse error when using the user controls in another project/solution. The app builds and deploys fine, though...